# javascript button show/hide on text changed

Tags: javascript, button, toggle

I want to show and hide a button by using java script.

My problem is that the button should be hide on page load and when I changed the text in text box then button should be show.

thanks.....

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) so far? (Note: you haven't actually asked a question here, or described a technical difficulty that you're having, you've basically said "I need this, please do it for me".)

Comment: it is not a site where everyone is here to give you what you want. Here are the programmers ready to help you if you are sucked some where.Try to do your self if you are getting problem then ask question .

Answer (score 13, accepted):

pls, Check this page and tell if this is what you wanted.

Basically, you need to use onchange event to do whatever you want to do.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
window.onload=function(){
  document.getElementById("button").style.display='none';

}
function showButton(){
  document.getElementById("button").style.display='block';
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" id="button" value="New Button"/>
Change the text in Input Box. Then Button will be show<br/><br/>
<input type="text" id="userText" value="Change the text" onchange="showButton()"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try with jQuery:

```
$("#yourInput").bind("change", function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    if (value && value.length > 0) {
        // Exist text in your input
        $("#yourButton").show();
    } else {
        $("#yourButton").hide();
    }
});
```

For non-jQuery:

```
function onchangeInput() {
    var value = this.value;
    if (value && value.length > 0) {
        // Exist text in your input
        document.getElementById("yourButton").style.visibility = "visible";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("yourButton").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
}

window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("yourButton").style.visibility = "hidden";
    var el = document.getElementById("yourInput");
    if (el.addEventListener) {
        el.addEventListener("change", onchangeInput, false);
    } else {
        el.attachEvent('onchange', onchangeInput);
    }
}
```

Again, don't show/hide a button, just disable it, that make the best user experience.

Comment: he has not tagged question with jquery. So, answer should be in pure java script :(

Comment: If you're interested in the jQuery version ... I had to modify the above to $("#yourInput").on("change keyup", function() { ... } . The rest was very helpful.

Comment: @AlexanderKim what do you mean? I have both answers for jQuery and non-jQuery. Haven't you try it?

Answer (score 0):

You could style the css to visibilty:hidden then in javascript add an event listner like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var box = document.getElementById('box');
  var textbox = document.getElementById('textbox');
  textbox.addEventListener("focus",showbox,false);
  function showbox() {
      box.style.visibility = 'visible';
   }
```

That would make it appear on focus but if you wanted to take it a step further you could add another event listener for a keystroke when the textbox is focused on. That would probably work.

Answer (score 0):

This is to hide/show a div based on text changed in text box.

With JQuery

`<script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function () {
            document.getElementById("submitdiv").style.display = 'none';
        }
        $(function () {
            $('.Name').on('keyup change', function () {
                if (this.value.length > 0) {
                    $('#submitdiv').show();
                } else {
                    $('#submitdiv').hide();
                }
            });
        });
    </script>`

HTML

```
<%:Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName,  new { @class ="Name"}) %>
<div id="submitdiv">
            <button type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right value-set" id="btnLogin">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This is to hide/show a div based on text changed in text box.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
<script>
  function
  changeButton() {
    document.getElementById("changeButton").innerHTML = "Insert text for button";
    document.getElementById("changeButton").removeAttribute("hidden");
  }
</script>
```

```html
<button hidden id="changeButton"></button>
```